# Old TV show with ghost attacking settlers on Mars

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv, mars

Looking for an old TV show that dealt with Mars, aliens and ghost that would attack the settlers. Can not remember if it was from the '70s or '80s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This is a very terse description, though. Please take a look at the prompts in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to add any further details that you may recall. The more info you can give us, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you. In particular, it would be helpful to know in roughly which year or decade you watched this. Also, was there one ghost or several?

Comment: there is a movie called Ghosts of Mars and also in Bradbury's The Martian Chronicles the Martians, shown to be dead for many thousands of years, appear as ghosts to humans and actually see humans as ghosts but there is no attacking from them.

Comment: Could be the episode of the X-Files episode "Space"? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0751207/?ref_=ttep_ep9

Answer (score 2):

Is this the TV miniseries, ***[The Martian Chronicles](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080242/)*** (1980)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Chronicles_(miniseries)):

> *The Martian Chronicles* is a 1980 television 3 episode miniseries based on Ray Bradbury's 1950 book *The Martian Chronicles* and dealing with the exploration of Mars and the inhabitants there. The series starred Rock Hudson, Darren McGavin, Bernadette Peters, Roddy McDowall, Fritz Weaver, Barry Morse, and Maria Schell. It was aired on NBC in January 1980 in three episodes with a total running time of just over four hours (nearly five hours on the DVD version). The series depicts Mars as having a "thin atmosphere" which humans can breathe with water-filled canals and desert-like vegetation. The miniseries was directed by Michael Anderson and written by Richard Matheson.

From the Wikipedia description of the second episode, "The Settlers."

> In September 2006, the Martian colonists start to encounter strange phenomena. David Lustig, presumed dead six years ago with the rest of Earth's Second Expedition to Mars, returns to his parents in Lustig Creek. He expresses an intense aversion to visiting First Town, the chief colony on Mars; when his parents insist on going there anyway, he suddenly goes missing. At the same time, **a pair of newly-arrived missionaries, Father Peregrine and Father Stone, are rescued from a landslide by a group of mysterious blue lights. Father Stone wants to return to First Town, but Father Peregrine insists on seeking out the blue lights; when he leaves his sleeping companion and climbs to the top of a cliff and steps off, one of them appears and saves him again. They reveal themselves to be non-corporeal Martians from over 250 million years ago who live in the hills, supposedly at one with God.** They tell Father Peregrine, who has vowed to build a church in the hills with a blue sphere in place of a cross, to return to his own people and minister to them.

You can view Father Peregrine's encounter with the non-corporeal Martians at around the 45:24 mark in the video below.